# Tooltip following mouse for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a website where hundreds of spans exist that I need to have tooltips for. Each tooltip includes important information about each span. Think of it like a contacts book where each span is an image of the contact and when you hover over the image, their name/contact info appears.

I have it so the tooltip follows your mouse and although it works fine for me, on some other computers, the tooltips lag quite a bit because of the large number of spans. It takes a few seconds for the tooltip to appear and is very choppy. The smaller the data size, the faster it is. 
What I've tried doing in Javascript is:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;

    for(var i = 0; i <  document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-span").length; i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-span")[i].style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
        document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-span")[i].style.left = (x + 10) + 'px';
    }
});
```

The lag is quite unbearable so I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this or not. Thanks in advance for the help.

HTML(I'm using Vue):

```
<div v-for="item in userInventory">
   <div v-if="item.data.quality == 6">
      <div class="item item--rare tooltip2"
         :class="`item--${item.item_type.name}`"
         style="border-color: #FFD700;"
         v-if="userInventorySelected.indexOf(item.assetid) !== -1"
         >
         <span class="tooltip-span">{{ item.data.name }}<br /><br />DATA: {{ item.data.num}}</span>
         <div class="item--bg" :style="`background-image:url(IMGLINK);`"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
  <div v-if="item.data.quality == 11">
      <div class="item item--rare tooltip2"
         :class="`item--${item.item_type.name}`"
         style="border-color: #FFD700;"
         v-if="userInventorySelected.indexOf(item.assetid) !== -1"
         >
         <span class="tooltip-span">{{ item.data.name }}<br /><br />DATA: {{ item.data.num}}</span>
         <div class="item--bg" :style="`background-image:url(IMGLINK);`"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I can't say for sure what's the best way to go around your problem without a little more info. But here are a couple of things that you can try to figure it out on your own to decrease the lag: 1) maintain only one tooltip element, and change the data of that tooltip according to which element the mouse is hovering. 2) you are looping in linear time over all your tooltip elements, you may want to look into javascript objects to decrease the lookup time for the element.

Comment: You need tooltip for all spans when when you move on body?

Comment: Yeah, I need a tooltip for every span, only one appearing at a time depending on the the span.

Comment: can you also post the html?

Comment: I added some of the HTML, my HTML is rather large so that's just an example of where I'd be using the tooltip

Comment: Also @Marcelo, thanks for the suggestions. Wouldn't I still have the same issue if I have to find the element that the mouse is hovering over in order to return the correct data?

Comment: @Anthony you can use e.target to check which element the mouse is hovering. Build a hash that maps each element to the correct data that it has to show, and just retrieve the data from the obj using the element id or something. If you id your span elements like this "span-number-{id}", you can get the id by doing e.target.id, and then your_map[e.target.id]. That should help a little. Then only mantain one tooltip, and change the data accordingly. And that should help A LOT.

Comment: Oh I didn't see your post @MarceloPerrella I just managed to add a unique ID for every element. However I think the problem seems to be that on slower computers, e.target doesn't update fast enough. I'm testing out e.target on my laptop right now and when moving from one element to another, there's a huge delay. That's without having any tooltip...Is there something I can do to get around that? Because even with your solution, if e.target is delayed then the tooltip will also be delayed. Thanks

Comment: You can try to add an event listener to every element directly, instead of a single one to the document.body. However, I think this should actually make it worse, but I might be wrong, it's worth a try.

I can't think of any other solution that might help performance... what is the average and the worst case scenario for the amount of items that will render the tooltip? 200? 300? 1000?

Comment: So I actually figured out the issue...It has nothing to do with the javascript...So for my tooltip2 class, I had tooltip2, tooltip2 span, and tooltip2:hover span.
I moved the css from the hover class to the regular tooltip2 span, then made it so by default the visibility was hidden. The only css I have in the hover class is making the visibility= visible. This seems to have fixed the issue..

Comment: Also about your latest suggestion, the number of items will only be going up from here. Should be well over 1000 soon and it will never drop under. I'm still going to try your suggestion before with the unique span IDs just because it should look cleaner and may even help once I get more items. As of right now though, the issue has been completely fixed. Thanks again for the help @MarceloPerrella

Comment: Good job. But you shouldn't ignore optimization. If you are gonna render that many items, take a look at lazy loading and pagination. That number of elements can really make the website experience feel sluggish, so watch out. You should NEVER be rendering 1000 items at a time.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at lazy loading but was working on a few other things first. I'm planning on making only a small number of items appear on load and then add an infinite scrolling feature just so I wouldn't load thousands of items at a time. That's one of my next steps, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is if there is a mouse move on items will class `tooltip2` you want to get the `span.tooltip-span` inside to follow your mouse.

Since you are going for a native implementation add method closest since we are using it below

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY;
  var container = e.target.closest('.tooltip2');
  if (container && container.querySelector('.tooltip-span')) {
    var target = container.querySelector('.tooltip-span');
    target.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    target.style.left = (x + 10) + 'px';
  }
});
```

Make sure to define closest method at the top
I am using a method call closest its the idea from JQuery. I was not sure if you have access to jQuery or not, If you are not using jQuery you need to define the closest method like this.

```
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
  Element.prototype.closest = 
  function(s) {
      var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
          i,
          el = this;
      do {
          i = matches.length;
          while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {};
      } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement)); 
      return el;
  };
}
```

---

If you are using jQuery donot add the above snippet of adding method closest, the below snippet will just work

```
$(document.body).mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY;
  var container = $(e.target).closest('.tooltip2');
  if (container && container.find('.tooltip-span')) {
    var target = container.find('.tooltip-span');
    target.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    target.style.left = (x + 10) + 'px';
  }
});
```

---

Update 2: Using jquery event delegation

```
$(document.body).on('mousemove', '.tooltip2', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.tooltip-span').css({left: e.clientX + 10, top: e.clientY +20});
});
```

Comment: Ok I checked it seems you need closest method to work this based on your structure. I have updated the answer hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for the update, so your fix now makes it so it will always show the tooltip no matter what, but we're back to the first issue where it's too laggy. It takes roughly 2 seconds for the tooltip to appear.

Comment: with jquery or native?

Comment: That's with native

Comment: I see that you have jquery can you try the other jquery snippet?

Comment: when you say laggy you dont mean on IE or anything right?

Comment: I'm trying to use the Jquery right now, it's failing when assigning the mouse location because target.style is undefined

Comment: And no I'm using Chrome.

Comment: OK I am taking a different approach, while you try the jquery implementation

Comment: Alright thanks, and yeah I'll keep playing around with the Jquery

Comment: I got the Jquery to work by changing the setting the target var to "container.find('.tooltip-span3').get()[0];"
It wasn't returning the right stuff beforehand. Like the native code, it works but it's still lagging by 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Same issue, it's still a 2 second delay :/ Also just a note, on my site if you select "All Bots" and select a specific bot, the tooltips are almost instant, almost all these solutions work perfectly including my original code. The issue here is just having so many items.

Comment: sorry man. I helped as i could maybe rather than document.body you can put it to botcontainer with an id in the last update. It seems that some other event is interfering maybe cant say for sure. It works fine from my machine

Comment: I understand. It's weird because on my desktop PC, it also works completely fine. But on some machines it's just too slow. I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: So I actually figured out the issue...It has nothing to do with the javascript...So for my tooltip2 class, I had tooltip2, tooltip2 span, and tooltip2:hover span.
I moved the css from the hover class to the regular tooltip2 span, then made it so by default the visibility was hidden. The only css I have in the hover class is making the visibility= visible. This seems to have fixed the issue..Selecting your answer as the best since all of these solutions did technically work :) Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = null;
var element = document.getElementById('SomeElementYouWantToAnimate');

function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  var progress = timestamp - start;
  element.style.transform = 'translateX(' + Math.min(progress / 10, 200) + 'px)';
  if (progress < 2000) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I tried using this but it didn't end up making a difference. Thanks though.